# What changed with solidity this Sunday? Contract deployment is not working anymore with "function should be payable" error

Tags: blockchain, solidity

I was successfully testing my smart contract using remix editor, and starting this weekend my contract is not deploying anymore, even I have not applied any changes to it.

This is the part of the code which fails while I debug the error (marked line #5):

```
1        constructor(address _router) public ERC20("Test Token", "TEST") payable {
2            IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Rtr = IUniswapV2Router02(_router);
4    
5            address _uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Rtr.factory()).createPair(address(this), _uniswapV2Rtr.WETH());
6            ...
7        }
```

Deployed gives me this error:

> creation of TestToken errored: VM error: revert. revert The transaction has been reverted to the initial state. Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance. Debug the transaction to get more information.

I don't understand what has been changed on deployer, and debugger does not specify which function should be defined as payable. And code was working perfectly before this Sunday. Which function deployer want me to make payable? And why this happens that code was working before? Does solidity applied some changes on the engine?

Comment: Is there a contract on the `_router` address implementing the `IUniswapV2Router02` interface? Same question for address `_uniswapV2Rtr.factory()` implementing the `IUniswapV2Factory` interface. It's possible that you're trying to deploy the contract on an emulator network (such as Remix VM) that had the other contracts deleted for some reason. Or that you used to deploy them on a network that contains these contracts but now you have changed to a different network that doesn't have them... Please provide steps to reproduce your issue.

Comment: @PetrHejda here is reproduction code: https://pastecode.io/s/w6eg8oiq, just paste it, compile and try to deploy with three parameters of any address

Comment: This won't work on the Remix VM as there are no contracts on the addresses specified in my first comment. What environment are you using (Remix VM, Ropsten, Ethereum mainnet, ...)? Can you check that there are in fact the expected contracts deployed on the expected addresses?

Comment: That explains a lot @PetrHejda, I tried on "Intected Web3" and all works as expected, somehow I was confused with this VM versus blockchain on the web. Thank you